# Signature popup in sencha touch on click

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want signature popup in my application.
'https://market.sencha.com/extensions/signature-pad-field'
This works for me but It opens one panel then on click on that panel it opens signature popup.
But I directly want to open Signature popup.
Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By using below code as your "/signaturefield/app/view/Signature.js", you can achieve this:

```
Ext.define('myApp.view.Signature', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    requires: [
        'Ext.form.Panel',
        'Ext.form.FieldSet'
    ],
config: {
        layout: 'card',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'formpanel',         
            padding: '10 10 10 10',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                hidden: true,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'signaturefield',
                    id: 'signatureField',
                    sigWidth: 350,
                    sigHeight: 150,
                    label:'Enter Signature',
                    labelWidth: '20%'
                }]
            },{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Get Data',
                margin:'0 0 10 0',
                action: 'getSignature'
            },{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Set Data',
                action: 'setSignature'
            }]
        }]
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.callParent();
        Ext.getCmp('signatureField').openCanvasSheet();
    }
});
```

Hope this will be helpful :)